# Why can't I access the firestore values in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Using the example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-example-tab-).

I modified some code to output the the *message* `onTap` as follows:

The `List` is generated with real values from firestore.
*but* the output is blank. It's not empty, as I tested with another set of output.
How can I retrieve these real values to use in `onTap` event handler?

```
....
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: messageCount,
  itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
    final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
    final dynamic message = document['message'];
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
         message != null ? message.toString() : '<No message retrieved>',
      ),
      subtitle: Text('Message ${index + 1} of $messageCount'),
      onTap: (){
        print(message.toString());

        // OUTPUT: (Nothing)
      },
    );
  },
);
....
```

```
onTap: (){
  print(message.toString().isEmpty ? 'Empty' : 'Not Empty');
  //OUTPUT: Not Empty 

  print(message== null ? 'Null' : 'Not Null');
  //OUTPUT: Not Empty 

},
```

Comment: From where you are getting messageCount?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using StreamBuilder or a future builder to load firestore data. Can I see the implementation there?

Comment: I'm using the code from example https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-example-tab- .I only included the modified part from the code in the post. `messageCount` is also included in that code.

Comment: Please not that data is recieved. Even shown in the list. Just the *variable* that is acting weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TLDR: Updating the database values worked.*

This must be the most weirdest thing I have seen.
But instead of the Text itself, I tried printing the length of it and it has same length as the text it had in ListTile.

Then I checked the firebase database. My findings:

- Data was visible
- Plain text - English
- Selecting the data and copy pasting it on a notepad pasted Nothing

- **Retyping the data made the app to work as expected.**

I didn't think of it before, but how the data was initially added to database might have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get your variable printed in `onTap` may lie somewhere else, e.g. in that you are possibly running other version of your app than your current code corresponds to. Try hard resetting the app and make sure you refresh the code on the emulator. Don't open the app manually from the emulator, it can load older version of your code.

I recreated exact the same code from Flutter example and it works perfectly fine (message gets printed correctly when tapping on a list tile as expected).

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firestore Example', home: MyHomePage(firestore: firestore)));
}

class MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageList({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore
          .collection("messages")
          .orderBy("created_at", descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: messageCount,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            final dynamic message = document['message'];
            return ListTile(
              trailing: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => document.reference.delete(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              ),
              title: Text(
                message != null ? message.toString() : '<No message retrieved>',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Message ${index + 1} of $messageCount'),
              onTap: () {
                print(message.toString());
                // THIS ACTUALLY WORKS !!
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  CollectionReference get messages => firestore.collection('messages');

  Future<void> _addMessage() async {
    await messages.add(<String, dynamic>{
      'message': 'Hello world!',
      'created_at': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }

  Future<void> _runTransaction() async {
    firestore.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
      final allDocs = await firestore.collection("messages").getDocuments();
      final toBeRetrieved =
          allDocs.documents.sublist(allDocs.documents.length ~/ 2);
      final toBeDeleted =
          allDocs.documents.sublist(0, allDocs.documents.length ~/ 2);
      await Future.forEach(toBeDeleted, (DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
        await transaction.delete(snapshot.reference);
      });

      await Future.forEach(toBeRetrieved, (DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
        await transaction.update(snapshot.reference, {
          "message": "Updated from Transaction",
          "created_at": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        });
      });
    });

    await Future.forEach(List.generate(2, (index) => index), (item) async {
      await firestore.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
        await Future.forEach(List.generate(10, (index) => index), (item) async {
          await transaction.set(firestore.collection("messages").document(), {
            "message": "Created from Transaction $item",
            "created_at": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _runBatchWrite() async {
    final batchWrite = firestore.batch();
    final querySnapshot = await firestore
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("created_at")
        .limit(12)
        .getDocuments();
    querySnapshot.documents
        .sublist(0, querySnapshot.documents.length - 3)
        .forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      batchWrite.updateData(doc.reference, {
        "message": "Batched message",
        "created_at": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      });
    });
    batchWrite.setData(firestore.collection("messages").document(), {
      "message": "Batched message created",
      "created_at": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
    batchWrite.delete(
        querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 2].reference);
    batchWrite.delete(querySnapshot.documents.last.reference);
    await batchWrite.commit();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Firestore Example'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: _runTransaction,
            child: Text("Run Transaction"),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: _runBatchWrite,
            child: Text("Batch Write"),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: MessageList(firestore: firestore),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addMessage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I still can't get it working. I am using only the Listing function (no deleting/bulk transactions). I copy pasted code from cloud. And the one you provided with.

Comment: Though, yours doesn't have the `final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(...` . Why so?

Comment: I loaded all the credentials via google-services.json file that you download when setting up your app on Firebase. You put this file in ./android/app/ folder.

Comment: Oh. That was how I tried at first. Thought it was something wrong with my code and spent 3 days without considering the database. Thanks a lot :D